# Vsts deny access to tasks board

Tags: azure-pipelines-build-task

I have an user in vsts that need to use test manager.
In test manager the user need to create and change test plans and run tests too.

But I want to limit the access that this user have of taks.

Is it possible to block this user of viewing taks board?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible for now.

If you added the user to your team project, he/she can view the task board.

I posted an user voice [set permission for task board](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/20393683-set-permission-for-task-board), you can vote and follow up.